# Load a page (with css and js enbedded) from base64 string

Tags: javascript, cordova, base64

I'm trying to create a mobile web application (for Android+iOS in phonegap and jquery mobile) that would be a container for another web applications downloaded from my webserver. Applications would be downloaded as a one-page site with scripts and css embedded in . These files are holded in a database as base64 strings.

Can you suggest me how to create and open a webpage which is not a file, but a base64 string?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know the *MIME*, e.g. for a html document it could be *text/html*, create a *dataURI*.

```
var duri = 'data:text/html;base64,' + base64data;
```

You can then treat this like any *URL*, e.g. open a new window or set as the *src* of an `<iframe>`.

Comment: It worked, but not exactly. Javascripts from base64data not working. For example I got errors: var is not defined and $ is not defined...